# How to make QDoc shipped with Qt 5.11.2 work under Windows 7?

Tags: qt, windows-7, qdoc

I have recently moved to Qt 5.11.2.

When I try to run `qdoc.exe` as an external tool from Qt Creator:

```
%{CurrentProject:QT_INSTALL_BINS}\qdoc.exe
```

with the following arguments:

```
%{CurrentProject:Path}/%{CurrentProject:Name}.qdocconf
```

in the General Message panel it is reported that the program is executed and has ended. There is no error, but the documentation is not generated.

When I try to run `qdoc.exe` from the command prompt, I get the following error:

> The program can't start, because api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have searched the whole system for `api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll` and it is indeed missing.

I took the dll from a Window 10 installation and put it in the same folder as the executable. The result is the same.

How to fix that?

Comment: Greetings from BW. I found [How To Fix Api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll is Missing / Not Found Error Messages](https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/windows-8-pro/api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0-dll/). Please, scroll down to the bottom. There is a list of 10 items to do. For me, it looks like just copying the DLL is not enough. I also found [MSDN: API Sets for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186421(v=vs.85).aspx) where it seems to belong to.

Comment: Actually, I had expected to find some kind of redist on MSDN which would ensure correct side-by-side installation but I couldn't find anything. May be, I gave up my search too early...

Comment: @Scheff, thank you very much! I will read and try that and make you aware of the results.

Comment: @Scheff, For now I have managed to try some of the steps, without success. Meanwhile I have set up a new Windows 10 VM and there I am able to run qdoc.exe, although there are other problems with it, which I will report separately. In any case, I keep on trying to solve the problems and I will give a feedback on the progress.

Comment: I'm looking forward to read your self-answer.

Comment: @Scheff, for now there are no chances for such one.