# Why does Q_OBJECT break QDoc?

Tags: c++, qt, qdoc, qt5.11

## Problem

Since the upgrade from Qt 5.10 to Qt 5.11 I have started having problems to generate a documentation with [QDoc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-index.html) for my existing projects.

One of the many issues are missing functions in the documentation, although the corresponding comments exist in the source code.

## Research

I have managed to narrow the issue down to the inclusion of the `Q_OBJECT` macro, as shown by the provided code example (see below).

This is indeed mentioned in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/23-qdoc-configuration-cppvariables.html#cpp-ignoredirectives):

> If not specified by the `Cpp.ignoretokens` or `Cpp.ignoredirectives` variables, non-standard constructs (typically macros) can result in erroneous documentation.

`Q_OBJECT` is not supposed to cause problems though, because just a little bit further it is written:

> The `Q_OBJECT` macro, however, is an exception: QDoc recognizes this particular non-standard construct, so there is no need specifying it using the `Cpp.ignoredirectives` variable.

In any case I do include [`qt-cpp-defines.qdocconf`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/doc/global/qt-cpp-defines.qdocconf) in my `qdocconf` file.

I have also tried to manually add `Q_OBJECT` to the ignore list

```
Cpp.ignoredirectives += Q_OBJECT
```

but the result is the same.

I experience the described issue under Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17. [Under Windows 7 I cannot execute `qdoc.exe` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52509422/5366641).

What is the correct configuration of `qdocconf` to overcome this issue?

## Minimal example

For a quick reproduction (in the real situation the declarations and the implementations are split and proper comments are added), please consider the following setup:

*Foo.h*

```
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject
{
//  Q_OBJECT // <-- uncomment this to break QDoc
public:
    Foo() {}

    void boo() {}

protected:
    void moo() {}
};
```

*Foo.cpp*

```
#include "Foo.h"

/*!
    \class Foo
 */
```

*test.qdocconf*

```
include($QT_INSTALL_DOCS/global/compat.qdocconf)
include($QT_INSTALL_DOCS/global/fileextensions.qdocconf)
include($QT_INSTALL_DOCS/global/qt-cpp-defines.qdocconf)
include($QT_INSTALL_DOCS/global/macros.qdocconf)

# Uncoment this for a test
# Cpp.ignoredirectives += Q_OBJECT

outputdir   = html
headerdirs  = .
sourcedirs  = .
exampledirs = .
imagedirs   = ./images
```

## Results

- Good result (without `Q_OBJECT`)

Executing `qdoc.exe test.qdocconf` I get more or less the following:

> - Foo
>
> **Contents**
>
> - Public Functions
> - Protected Functions
> - Detailed Description
>
> ## Foo Class
>
> - List of all members, including inherited members
>
> **Public Functions**
>
> Foo()
>
> void  boo()
>
> **Protected Functions**
>
> void  moo()
>
> **Detailed Description**
>
> **Member Function Documentation**
>
> Foo::Foo()
>
> Default constructs an instance of Foo.
>
> void Foo::boo()
>
> [protected] void Foo::moo()

- Bad result (with `Q_OBJECT`)

Uncommenting the `Q_OBJECT` macro and running `qdoc.exe` again yelds the following result:

> - Foo
>
> **Contents**
>
> - Detailed Description
>
> ## Foo Class
>
> **Detailed Description**

**IMPORTANT:** `Foo`, `moo` and `boo` are gone.

Comment: This also happens with Q_PROPERTY as well. For me, some class class work correctly with Q_OBJECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is a few years old already but I wanted to post an answer for future searchers that find this. I had this issue for both Q_OBJECT and Q_INVOKABLE macros in my .cpp file.

The solution is either to use an undocumented command in your .qdocconf file, `includepaths`, or to pass `-I` parameters to your command when you run `qdoc`.

I will only show how I got it working with my config.qdocconf file

```
...
# undocumented feature that simulates passing -I parameters to the command line
includepaths = . \
           .. \
           $QT_INSTALL_HEADERS \
           $QT_INSTALL_HEADERS/QtCore \
           $QT_INSTALL_HEADERS/QtGui \
           $QT_INSTALL_HEADERS/QtQuick \
           $QT_INSTALL_DOCS
...
```

You can also use absolute paths instead of `$QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` if needed.

An easy way to see where those special variables point to is to run `qmake -query` (use an absolute path to your qt install bin if needed for your `qmake` command)

Edit: For me, the `$QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` = `C:/Qt/5.12.9/msvc2017_64/include`

Edit 2: make sure you have clang installed on your system (via [chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/packages/llvm), [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm), apt, or others) and if on windows that you run `set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=C:\Program Files\LLVM` before you run qdoc - Instructions here: [Installing Clang for QDoc](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdoc-guide-clang.html)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer! I will test your solution as soon as can.

Comment: added a few edits, with extra info that will hopefully help you and any others that find this

Comment: The issue is still valid and your solution fixes it, which is wonderful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with is to add the following preprocessor directives to the `Q_OBJECT` macro:

```
#ifndef Q_QDOC
    Q_OBJECT
#endif //Q_QDOC
```

`Q_QDOC` is defined in the included `qt-cpp-defines.qdocconf`, so `QDoc` skips the macro, but it is not defined within the build system and the code compiles as usual.